# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and spring vault

Tags: spring, spring-vault, property-placeholder

I have 2 property sources file system and vault. i am using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to read data from file. Now to initialize vault (url etc) is coming from file. So vault is not initializing as properties are not available as spring resolves the properties later once it loads all the properties. Please suggest a way so that i can trigger vault initialization after file is loaded and both sources can be merged as well. Thanks